# Floating point rounding error moves reported result inside range

Tags: c, floating-point, rounding, floating-accuracy

I am working on a function to report test results together with lower and upper limit for that specific test result. These three values will be converted with a specified formula (aX + b)/c where X is testResult/lowerLimit/upperLimit and a,b and c are floating point numbers.

If the reported test result is inside/outside the specified limits before the conversion it shall also be inside/outside the limit after the conversion in order to ensure the validity of the reported results.

I have identified two cases where an invalid test result will move inside the range after the conversion but I have yet to find a case where the test result is inside the range before the conversion and will be outside the specified limits after conversion. Can this case even occur? I don't believe so? Can it?

Below is some code that produces the two cases that I mentioned together with corrections to ensure the validity of the reported test result.

TLDR: Can the ((TRUE == insideLimitBefore) && (FALSE == insideLimitAfter)) case in the code below happen?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define TRUE    (uint8_t)0x01
#define FALSE   (uint8_t)0x00

int32_t LinearMapping(const int32_t input);
void Convert(int32_t testResult, int32_t lowerLimit, int32_t upperLimit);

int main(void)
{

    int32_t lowerLimit = 504;
    int32_t testResult = 503;
    int32_t upperLimit = 1000;

    printf("INPUT:\n\tLower limit:\t%d\t\n\tTest result:\t%d\t\n\tUpper limit:\t%d\t\n", lowerLimit, testResult, upperLimit);
    Convert(testResult, lowerLimit, upperLimit);

    lowerLimit = 500;
    testResult = 504;
    upperLimit = 503;

    printf("INPUT:\n\tLower limit:\t%d\t\n\tTest result:\t%d\t\n\tUpper limit:\t%d\t\n", lowerLimit, testResult, upperLimit);
    Convert(testResult, lowerLimit, upperLimit);

    return 0;
}

int32_t LinearMapping(const int32_t input)
{
    float retVal;

    const float a = 1.0;
    const float b = 1.0;
    const float c = 2.3;

    retVal = a * input;
    retVal += b;
    retVal /= c;

    return (int32_t)retVal;
}

void Convert(int32_t testResult, int32_t lowerLimit, int32_t upperLimit)
{
    uint8_t insideLimitAfter;
    uint8_t belowLowerLimit;
    uint8_t insideLimitBefore = ((lowerLimit <= testResult) && (testResult <= upperLimit)) ? TRUE : FALSE;

    if (FALSE == insideLimitBefore)
    {
        /* testResult is either below or above lowerLimit/upperLimit respectively */
        if (testResult < lowerLimit)
        {
            belowLowerLimit = TRUE;
        }
        else /* testResult > upperLimit */
        {
            belowLowerLimit = FALSE;
        }
    }

    testResult = LinearMapping(testResult);
    lowerLimit = LinearMapping(lowerLimit);
    upperLimit = LinearMapping(upperLimit);

    insideLimitAfter = ((lowerLimit <= testResult) && (testResult <= upperLimit)) ? TRUE : FALSE;

    if ((FALSE == insideLimitBefore) && (TRUE == insideLimitAfter))
    {
        if (TRUE == belowLowerLimit)
        {
            printf("OUTPUT:\n\tLower limit:\t%d\t\n\tTest result:\t%d\t\n\tUpper limit:\t%d\t\n", lowerLimit+1, testResult, upperLimit);
        }
        else /* belowLowerLimit == FALSE => testResult > upperLimit */
        {
            printf("OUTPUT:\n\tLower limit:\t%d\t\n\tTest result:\t%d\t\n\tUpper limit:\t%d\t\n", lowerLimit, testResult, upperLimit-1);
        }
    }
    else if ((TRUE == insideLimitBefore) && (FALSE == insideLimitAfter))
    {
       /* Is this case even possible? */
    }
    else
    {
        /* Do nothing */
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you condense this question down? Do you really need to paste up all the code? Buried deep is a good question here.

Comment: There's too much code here for me to really tell what's going on.  But I suspect this is going to boil down to [*Is floating point math broken?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Comment: It not a dupe of IFPMB.

Comment: @Bathsheba - I have a dupe hammer for C, so I'd prefer not to VTC until I can be sure that this is actually down to floating-point limitations.  (If you've looked at the code deeper than I have, and can tell me that's what the issue is, I'll trust you and gladly VTC :)

Comment: On a complete tangent: testing for truth as `TRUE == condition` is a bad idea, because truth in C is defined as anything non-zero.  Just use `condition` (and then for falsehood, use `!condition` for symmetry).

Comment: Ok, I've looked at this code more thoroughly now.  I think it boils down to: "if I have two integers `x` and `y`, and I apply a transform of the form `f(x) = (int)(a*(float)x + b) / c)` to each of them, can the relative order of `f(x)` and `f(y)` ever differ from that of the original `x` and `y`?"

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth This is not a [Is floating point math broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47940153/floating-point-rounding-error-moves-reported-result-inside-range/47941135#comment82850353_47940153) issue.   Had code used `int32_t` for `a,b,c` (no FP at all), the same core (well hidden) question applies.

Comment: @chux - Indeed, now that I spent more time deciphering the code, I agree that it's not really an FP issue (though one could argue there'd be a voodoo concern that FP makes this problem "worse" in some sense ;)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Yes, FP concerns where my first take too given the tags.  The `#define TRUE`, `if (FALSE == insideLimitBefore)`, empty code `/* Is this case even possible? */` all added their "charm".  Still, unless one knows the answer, it is a challenge to write a perfect question.

Comment: Although the underlying operations of floating-point addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division by a constant are non-strictly monotonic, C is not required to evaluate all expressions with the same precision. And although OP shows one routine being used for the transformation, that does not mean the C implementation uses the same code for each item being transformed; it might inline the function and use different code in different places. Then, one of the results might be subject to a double-rounding error, and that can break monotonicity.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: Why would you even consider whether this “boils down” to [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) Nothing in it suggests OP believes floating-point ought to be doing ideal math or that it is failing to operate in a way OP expected. It asks a perfectly sensible question about floating-point. When people ask about properties of floating-point arithmetic or for proofs or examples, please do not vote to close questions. Floating-point arithmetic has actual workings that can be inspected and analyzed.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - As I said above, I didn't vote to close, because I couldn't tell *what* the problem/question was, originally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> to find a case where the test result is inside the range before the conversion and will be outside the specified limits after conversion. Can this case even occur?

No, given sane  `a,b,c, lowerLimit, testResult, upperLimit`.

Given 3 values `lo,x,hi` that are `lo <= x <= hi` before the linear conversion in `LinearMapping()` the `lo_new <= x_new <= hi_new` will maintain the same relationship as long as the conversion is (positively) linear (no division by 0, `a`,`b`, `c` are not Not-A-Numbers).  No conversion of a `float` that is out of range of `int32_t`.

The primary reason is on edge cases of `x` just inside or at the limit, `[lo...hi]` , the `LinearMapping()` may reduce the effective precision of all 3.  The new `x` may now equal `lo` or `hi` and `==` favors "in range".  So no change in `lo <= x <= hi`.

OP originally found examples of "invalid test result will move inside the range after the conversion" because the `x` was just outside `[lo...hi]` and the effective precision reduction now made `x` equal to either `lo` or `hi`.  Since `==` favors "in range", the move from outside to inside is seen.

Note: if the `LinearMapping()` has a negative slope like -1, then `lo <= x <= hi` can easily be broken.   as `1 <= 2 <= 3` --> `-1 > -2 > -3`.  This makes `lowerLimit > upperLimit` which "in range" cannot be satisfied for any `x`.

---

For reference, OP's code simplified:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int LinearMapping(const int input) {
  const float a = 1.0;
  const float b = 1.0;
  const float c = 2.3;
  float retVal = a * input;
  retVal += b;
  retVal /= c;
  return (int) retVal;
}

void Convert(int testResult, int lowerLimit, int upperLimit) {
  printf("Before %d %s %d %s %d\n", lowerLimit,
      lowerLimit <= testResult ? "<=" : "> ", testResult,
      testResult <= upperLimit ? "<=" : "> ", upperLimit);
  testResult = LinearMapping(testResult);
  lowerLimit = LinearMapping(lowerLimit);
  upperLimit = LinearMapping(upperLimit);
  printf("After  %d %s %d %s %d\n\n", lowerLimit,
      lowerLimit <= testResult ? "<=" : "> ", testResult,
      testResult <= upperLimit ? "<=" : "> ", upperLimit);
}

int main(void) {
  Convert(503, 504, 1000);
  Convert(504, 500, 503);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Before 504 >  503 <= 1000
After  219 <= 219 <= 435

Before 500 <= 504 >  503
After  217 <= 219 <= 219
```

Answer (score 1):

> … I have yet to find a case where the test result is inside the range before the conversion and will be outside the specified limits after conversion. Can this case even occur? I don't believe so? Can it?

Yes, this can occur, in theory, although due to C behavior rather than due to the underlying floating-point operations. The C standard does not guarantee that IEEE-754 floating-point arithmetic is used or even that the same precision through evaluation of an expression, and this can cause identical inputs to an expression to have different results.

Although `LinearMapping` is shown as a single routine, the compiler may inline it. That is, where the routine is called, the compiler may replace the call with the body of the routine. Furthermore, when it does this in different places, it may evaluate the expressions using different methods. So, in this code, `LinearMapping` may be evaluated using different floating-point operations in each call:

```
testResult = LinearMapping(testResult);
lowerLimit = LinearMapping(lowerLimit);
upperLimit = LinearMapping(upperLimit);
```

This means that `(a * testResult + b) / c` might be evaluated using only 32-bit floating-point arithmetic, while `(a * upperLimit + b) / c` might be evaluated using 64-bit floating-point arithmetic, converted to 32-bit after the division. (I have merged your three assignment statements into one expression here for brevity. The issue applies either way.)

One consequence of this is double rounding. When a result is calculated with one precision and then converted to another, two roundings occur, one in the initial calculation and a second in the conversion. Consider an exact mathematical result that looks like this:

```
    1.xxxxx01011111111xxxx1xx
             ^       ^ Start of bits to be rounded in wider format.
             | Start of bits to be rounded in narrower format.
```

If this were the result of a calculation in the narrower format, we would examine the bits 011111111xxxx1xx and round them down (they are less than ½ at the position where we are rounding), so the final result would be 1.xxxxx01. However, if we do the calculation in the wider format first, the bits to be rounded away are 1xxxx1xx (more than ½), and these are rounded up, making the intermediate result 1.xxxxx0110000000. When we convert to the narrower format, the bits to be rounded away are 10000000, which is exactly the midpoint (½), so the round-to-nearest-ties-to-even rule tells us to round up, which makes the final result 1.xxxxx10.

Thus, even if `testResult` and `upperLimit` are equal, the results of applying `LinearMapping` to them may be unequal, and `testResult` may appear to be outside the interval.

There may be some ways to avoid this problem:

- If your C implementation conforms to Annex F of the C standard (which essentially says that it uses IEEE-754 operations and binds them to C operators in expected ways) or at least conforms to certain parts of it, then double rounding should not occur with well written source code.
- The C standard says an implementation should define `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` in `<float.h>`. If `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` is 0, it means all floating-point operations and constants are evaluated with their nominal type. In this case, double rounding will not occur if you use a single floating-point type in your source code. If `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` is 1, `float` operations are evaluated with `double`. In this case, you could avoid double rounding by using `double` instead of `float`. If it is 2, operations are evaluated with `long double`, and you could avoid double rounding by using `long double`. If `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` is -1, the floating-point format used for evaluation is indeterminable, so double rounding is a concern.
- For specific values or intervals of values and/or known floating-point formats, it might be possible to prove that double rounding does not occur. E.g., given that your inputs are all `int32_t`, that the linear mapping parameters are certain values, and that only 32-bit or 64-bit IEEE-754 binary floating-point is in use, it might be possible to prove double rounding does not occur.

Even if your implementation conforms to Annex F or defines `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` to be non-negative, you must still take care in your code not to use expressions that have type `double` which you then assign to objects of type `float`. This will cause double rounding because your source code explicitly requires it, rather than because C is lax about floating-point.

As a specific example, consider `(1.0 * 13546 + 1.0) / 2.3`. If the floating-point constants are represented in 64-bit binary floating-point (53-bit significands) and the expression is evaluated in 64-bit binary, the result is 5890.0000000000009094947017729282379150390625. However, if the same constants are used (in 64-bit binary) but the expression is evaluated with Intel’s 80-bit binary (64-bit significands) and then converted to 64-bit, the result is 5890.

In this case, the exact mathematical quotient is:

```
1.01110000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000001011…
                                                          ^ Bits rounded away in double.
```

If we round this in double, we can see the bits to be rounded away, 1000000000001011…, are greater than ½ at the rounding position, so we round up. If we round it in long double, the bits to be rounded away are 01011…. These round down, leaving:

```
1.011100000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000
                                                      ^ Bits rounded away in double.
```

Now, when we round to double, the bits to be rounded away are 10000000000, which is the midpoint. The rule says to round to make the low bit even, so the result is:

```
1.011100000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000
```